# Maven Errors: Multiple annotations found at this line for Spring Cloud configuration

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm configuration a configuration server with spring cloud, but meet error:

> Multiple annotations found at this line.

My spring boot version is 
`2.1.4.RELEASE`
JDK is Java 1.8
I'd like to use spring cloud the version should be `Greenwich.RELEASE`

My pom file are below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.chenlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>configuration-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>configurationservice</name>
    <description>configuration Service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Get error in the pom file. I have used `Maven->Update Project`. But it does not work. attached error here.
The full stack error a is here:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Failure to transfer org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was 
     cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: 
     Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/
     maven2): The operation was cancelled. org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.springframework.cloud:spring-
     cloud-config-client:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
     reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact 
     org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was 
     cancelled. at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:240) at 
     org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:208) at 
     org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:563) at 
     org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:481) at 
     org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:399) at 
     org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224) at 
     org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:338) at 
     org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:202) at 
     org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:212) at 
     org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:185) at 
     org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:116) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:628) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:
     63) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:525) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.lambda$1(ProjectRegistryManager.java:489) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:488) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:349) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:296) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:405) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:352) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1332) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:349) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:77) at 
     org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:42) at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:
     63)
    - Failure to transfer org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.60 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
     resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact 
     org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.60 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled. 
     org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.60 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/
     maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
     Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.60 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The 
     operation was cancelled. at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:240) at 
     org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:208) at 
     org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:563) at 
     org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:481) at 
     org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:399) at 
     org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224) at 
     org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:338) at 
     org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:202) at 
     org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:212) at 
     org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:185) at 
     org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:116) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:628) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:
     63) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:525) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.lambda$1(ProjectRegistryManager.java:489) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:488) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:349) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:296) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:405) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:352) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1332) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:349) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:77) at 
     org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:42) at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:
     63)
```

Comment: Looks like a network error

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks, as you said, I have remove all the files under `org.bouncycastle.*` and `org.springframework.cloud.*`. And then Maven->Update Project. This issue issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.60</version>
            <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```